# Limit of a term is positive or negative

Tags: limits

I have a fraction where I wanted to calculate the limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5^n-1}{-4^n+2^{n-1}}$$

My next step was to expand the fraction by $\frac1{5^n}$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1-\frac1{5^n}}{\left(\frac{-4}{5}\right)^n+\frac12\cdot \left( \frac25\right)^{n}}$$

---

*comment*

[Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/202857/bernard) make me aware of wrong transformation $-4^n\cdot \left(\frac15\right)^n\neq \left(\frac{-4}{5}\right)^n$

---

It is obvious that the denominator goes to $0$. But how can I show that the denominator approaches zero from the right without calculating the derivative?

Thanks to all who read the question.

Comment: Can you post an answer? I don´t know how to show it.

Comment: In the denominator, is it $-4^n$ or $(-4)^n$?

Comment: @DonThousand It doesn’t exist finite.

Comment: @Bernard Good question it is $-4^n$, I assume.

Comment: In this case, there's an error in the denominator of the second line.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, thanks. I will make a comment at my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your initial fraction is correct, you can use equivalents to simplify:

$5^n-1\sim_{n\to\infty} 5^n$, $\;-4^n+2^{n-1}\sim_{n\to\infty} -4^n$, so
$$\frac{5^n-1}{-4^n+2^{n-1}}\sim_{n\to\infty} -\Bigl(\frac54\Bigr)^n \to -\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks for your approach. But I cannot show (easily) that the denominator approaches zero from the right?

Comment: You can't, since it tends to $0$ from the left.

Comment: OK. But how I can show this? It is possible? Or we can just say that $4^n$ grows faster than $2^n$?

Comment: $-1+\frac12\Bigl(\frac12\Bigr)^n=-1+\frac1{2^{n+1}}$ is obviously negative.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks for your answer and your clariyfing comment.

Answer (score 3):

Let consider instead

$$\frac{5^n}{4^n} \frac{1-\frac1{5^n}}{-1+\frac12\cdot \left( \frac24\right)^{n}}\to \infty \cdot (-1)$$

Comment: Have you omitted $\lim_{n\to \infty}$? And how do you get $\infty (-1)$? And what does it mean?

Comment: It is implicitely assumed, it’s a allowed notation when it is clear from the context. Anyway use the full notation in your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1).